# How can I use "NER" for German Language with stanford-corenlp?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use nlp for german language but it does not work!
I was making the pipeline and then NER to find the entity of each element in sentence which is working perfectly for English but not Geman language!
I also added German language to maven...
here is my pipeline:

```
public class Pipeline {
private static Properties properties;
private static String propertiesName = "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner";
private static StanfordCoreNLP stanfordCoreNLP;

private Pipeline() {
}

static {
    properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("annotators", propertiesName);
}

public static StanfordCoreNLP getPipeline(){
    if (stanfordCoreNLP == null){
        stanfordCoreNLP = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);
    }
    return stanfordCoreNLP;
}
```

}

and here is my NER:

```
public class NER {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StanfordCoreNLP stanfordCoreNLP = Pipeline.getPipeline();
    String text = "hello My name is xxx. I live in Austria.";

    CoreDocument coreDocument = new CoreDocument(text);
    stanfordCoreNLP.annotate(coreDocument);

    List<CoreLabel> coreLabelList = coreDocument.tokens();

    for (CoreLabel coreLabel: coreLabelList){
        String ner = coreLabel.get(CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println(coreLabel.originalText() + "->"+ner);
    }
}
```

}

and here is my maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.2</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <classifier>models-german</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

what should I change or add to use it also for German Language?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using a slightly different approach, having `stanford-corenlp-4.2.2.jar` and `stanford-corenlp-4.2.1-models-german.jar` in my class path:

```
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP("german");
CoreDocument document = pipeline.processToCoreDocument(text);
```

Based on this information [Using CoreNLP on other human languages](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html).

Comment: Did you also try to train your own model?